# Java Android studio and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

I am trying to populate a spinner with values from my firebase database.

```
fdatabase = database.getReference();


fdatabase.child("SPORTS").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final List<String> Sports = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String SportName = dataSnapshot.child("SportName").getValue(String.class);
            Sports.add(SportName);
        }
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SportSpinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> SportAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RegComplete.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Sports);
            SportAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(SportAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here is the code and i'll share a snapshot of my database as well. Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Yes, you haven't said what's the problem

Comment: The spinner won't show anything, "I am not getting any specific errors"

Comment: This is very limited info provided by you. Are you getting any data in your Arraylist ?
I would like you to extract the logic of populating the spinner out to another method and call that from on data change. Also try to pass some other set of data to find if the problem is with getting data from firebase or populating it in the spinner. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. One thing bothering me is, Is my data structure good ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your peace of code and modified the child names to get a value of my own database and it worked, so my guess is, that your code does not fit to your data structure.
But it's hard to help you, if you don't provide us your data structure. You try to get the value of

```
yourDatabase/"SPORTS"/"Sportname"
```

But I bet, you are missing a key in between and you actually meant this:

```
yourDatabase/"SPORTS"/SOME MISSING KEY/"Sportname"
```

So, try to changed this line

```
String SportName = dataSnapshot.child("SportName").getValue(String.class);
```

into this:

```
String SportName = dataSnapshot.child(**MISSING KEY**).child("SportName").getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: @Mobeen Kazmi Did you find your mistake?

Comment: Thanks sir, I will try your solution ASAP. I think it will fix it, as i am really new to android and firebase. thank you so much

Comment: Thank you so much LocDoc01 your Solution Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Glad that I could help. Feel free to accept and/or vote on the answer, if it was helpful to you ;)

Comment: Accepted. I have posted another question i can use your help with. I am pretty new to android and keep running in problems because of it.